# Getting a result back from a stored procedure in Java

Tags: java, oracle11g

I am having the hardest time calling an Oracle stored procedure from a java runtime environment.  The stored procedure that I am calling has 2 parameters 1 in and 1 out.  Here is how I call the stored procedure... How do you get the resultSet from an Oracle ref_cursor

```
                ds = (DataSource)initialContext.lookup("JDBC/EPCD13DB");
                conn = ds.getConnection();
                callableStatement = conn.prepareCall(storedProcCall);
                callableStatement.setString(1, input1);
                callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);                      
                callableStatement.execute();//(ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(1);
                ResultSet rs = callableStatement.getResultSet();
                while(rs.next()){
                    Provider tempProv = new Provider();
                    tempProv.setResourceId(rs.getLong("res_id"));
                    tempProv.setFirstName(rs.getString("First_Name"));
                    tempProv.setLastName(rs.getString("Last_Name"));
                    tempProv.setMiddleName(rs.getString("Middle_Name"));
                    ObjList.add(tempProv);
                }
                rs.close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to retrieve the `ResultSet` with:

```
 ResultSet rSet = (ResultSet)callableStatement.getObject(2);
```

Comment: why getObject(2)?  I was trying getObject(1).  Is that asking for the second parameter?

Comment: @DmainEvent Because the OUT parameter is on the second position: `registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR)`

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you? Seems like you have to call getObject and cast it into a result set before querying on the result set.

Credit::  http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-callablestatement-stored-procedure-cursor-example/

Answer (score 0):

I believe it returns only one output(`oracle cursor`)

```
            ResultSet rs=(ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(2);
```

and then iterate your cursor result set for records inside:

```
           while(rs.next()){
                Provider tempProv = new Provider();
                tempProv.setResourceId(rs.getLong("res_id"));
                tempProv.setFirstName(rs.getString("First_Name"));
                tempProv.setLastName(rs.getString("Last_Name"));
                tempProv.setMiddleName(rs.getString("Middle_Name"));
                ObjList.add(tempProv);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In spring framework fetching database cursor results can be easily achieved. It has inbuilt classes like maprow, storedprocedure to serve the purpose. PFB the link

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-simple-jdbc-call-1